# How to save File object array in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to save the file object array in redux store.

This is the code about reducers

```
    case types.SET_PICTURE:
      console.log("action");
      console.log(action.newPictureFiles);
      console.log(action.newPictureDataURLs);
      return {
        ...state,
        inquiryForm: {
          ...state.inquiryForm,
          pictureFiles: [...action.newPictureFiles],
          pictureDataURLs: [...action.newPictureDataURLs]
        }
      };
```

This code is about dispatch

```
class Attachment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pictureFiles: this.props.pictureFiles,
      pictureDataURLs: this.props.pictureDataURLs,
      uploadedURLs: []
    };
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  onDrop(pictureFiles, pictureDataURLs) {
    // pictureFiles = [{File object}, {File object}, {File object}]
    console.log("onDrop")
    console.log(pictureFiles);
    console.log(pictureDataURLs);
    this.props.onSetPicture(pictureFiles, pictureDataURLs)
    this.setState({
      pictureFiles: pictureFiles,
      pictureDataURLs: pictureDataURLs,
    });
  }
```

console.log( action.newPictureFiles ) print well like this[[File object array in chrome dbg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkcl8.png)], after reducer function case types.SET_PICTURE:, redux print empty obj like this[[redux result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7hPb.png)]. Why reducers cannot save the File object in redux store. and How to fix it?

Comment: what's the result of console.log(action.newPictureFiles) ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you dispatch the action with those file array. did you convert the data to form data?.

Comment: @WilsonLiao 
like this image[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkcl8.png]

Comment: @TRomesh I attach the code more. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `action.newPictureFiles` has the file but it not shown because console log will print the file as an empty obj.

Please use this to log all your data considering your action.newPictureFiles is array of files.

```
action.newPictureFiles.forEach(file => {
    for (var pair of file.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
})
```

or just this for each file

```
for (var pair of file.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: console.log(action.newPictureFiles);  say like this image[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkcl8.png]
but, redux look like this image[https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7hPb.png]

Comment: sorry, I did not explain the question well. console.log( action.newPictureFiles ) print well, after reducer function `case types.SET_PICTURE:`, redux print empty obj like this[https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7hPb.png].

Comment: Your answer has incorrect information, the console is capable of printing file objects just fine. Only redux dev tools doesn't show it, since it tries to convert it to json

Comment: Can you please show us action creator `onSetPicture`

Comment: @Ferrybig Thank you, I'll check it again and it does well. Redux save File object but I couldn't see it well in the chrome redux window. When I try console.log(), I can find it. Thank you!!

Comment: @sachinkalekar ```  onSetPicture: (pictureFiles , pictureDataURLs) => {
    dispatch(actions.setPicture(pictureFiles , pictureDataURLs))
  }, ```

Comment: onSetPicture: (pictureFiles, pictureDataUrls) => (dispatch)  =>  dispatch(actions.setPicture(pictureFiles , pictureDataURLs));